# Ipopt error: malloc(): invalid size (unsorted) Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c++

I'm working with Ipopt C++ library (https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt).

Planning to work on optimization of trajectories soon, but for now I'm practicing on the simple tasks.

In particular I've been trying to solve this:

```
Find a set of N points on the 2D plane such that:
• the first and last point are positioned at (0, 0) and (10, 10), respectively;
• the distances between two consecutive points are equal;
• there is no point lying on a circle or radius 1 centered at (4, 4);
• the sum of the distances between consecutive points is minimized.
```

I wrote C++ code for finding the solution. It creates cvs file with optimized points.

```
#include "Ipopt/src/Interfaces/IpIpoptApplication.hpp"
#include "Ipopt/src/Interfaces/IpTNLP.hpp"
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream> // Include for file operations

using namespace Ipopt;

class PointSetProblem : public TNLP {
public:
    // Constructor
    PointSetProblem(int N, double distance, const std::vector<double>& obstacle, const std::vector<double>& pinit, const std::vector<double>& pfin)
        : N_(N), distance_(distance), obstacle_(obstacle), pinit_(pinit), pfin_(pfin) {}

    int getN() const {
        return N_;
    }

    // Define problem dimensions
    virtual bool get_nlp_info(Index& n, Index& m, Index& nnz_jac_g, Index& nnz_h_lag, IndexStyleEnum& index_style) {
        // Number of variables (2D coordinates for N points)
        n = 2 * N_;

        // Number of equality constraints (N-1 distances between points)
        m = N_ - 1;

        // Number of non-zero elements in the Jacobian of the constraints
        nnz_jac_g = 2 * (N_ - 1);

        // Number of non-zero elements in the Hessian of the Lagrangian (0 if not available)
        nnz_h_lag = 0;

        // Use C-style indexing
        index_style = TNLP::C_STYLE;
        return true;
    }

    // Define bounds for variables and constraints
    virtual bool get_bounds_info(Index n, Number* x_l, Number* x_u, Index m, Number* g_l, Number* g_u) {
    // Variable bounds (all points are in [0, 10] x [0, 10])
        for (int i = 0; i < N_; i++) {
            x_l[2 * i] = 0.0;   // x coordinate
            x_l[2 * i + 1] = 0.0; // y coordinate
            x_u[2 * i] = 10.0;   // x coordinate
            x_u[2 * i + 1] = 10.0; // y coordinate
        }

        // Constraint bounds (distances between points)
        for (int i = 0; i < N_ - 1; i++) {
            g_l[i] = 0.0; // Lower bound for distances
            g_u[i] = distance_; // Upper bound for distances
        }

        // Add constraints to avoid the circle of radius 1 centered at (4, 4)
        for (int i = 0; i < N_; i++) {
            double dx = x_l[2 * i] - obstacle_[0];
            double dy = x_l[2 * i + 1] - obstacle_[1];
            double distance_squared = dx * dx + dy * dy;
            g_l[N_ - 1 + i] = -1e20; // Ensure points are outside the circle
            g_u[N_ - 1 + i] = 1e20; // A large upper bound to ensure the circle constraint is not violated
        }

        return true;
    }

    // Define initial guess for the variables
    virtual bool get_starting_point(Index n, bool init_x, Number* x, bool init_z, Number* z_L, Number* z_U, Index m, bool init_lambda, Number* lambda) {
        // Initialize points with equally spaced distances
        for (int i = 0; i < N_; i++) {
            x[2 * i] = pinit_[0] + (pfin_[0] - pinit_[0]) * i / (N_ - 1);
            x[2 * i + 1] = pinit_[1] + (pfin_[1] - pinit_[1]) * i / (N_ - 1);
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Define the objective function
    virtual bool eval_f(Index n, const Number* x, bool new_x, Number& obj_value) {
        // Minimize the sum of distances between consecutive points
        obj_value = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N_ - 1; i++) {
            double dx = x[2 * (i + 1)] - x[2 * i];
            double dy = x[2 * (i + 1) + 1] - x[2 * i + 1];
            obj_value += std::sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Define the constraints
    virtual bool eval_g(Index n, const Number* x, bool new_x, Index m, Number* g) {
        // Calculate distances between consecutive points and use them as constraints
        for (int i = 0; i < N_ - 1; i++) {
            double dx = x[2 * (i + 1)] - x[2 * i];
            double dy = x[2 * (i + 1) + 1] - x[2 * i + 1];
            g[i] = std::sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Define the Jacobian of the constraints
    virtual bool eval_jac_g(Index n, const Number* x, bool new_x, Index m, Index nele_jac, Index* iRow, Index* jCol, Number* values) {
        // Structure of the Jacobian matrix
        if (values == NULL) {
            for (int i = 0; i < N_ - 1; i++) {
                iRow[2 * i] = i;
                jCol[2 * i] = 2 * i;
                iRow[2 * i + 1] = i;
                jCol[2 * i + 1] = 2 * i + 1;
            }
        } else {
            // Calculate the values of the Jacobian matrix
            for (int i = 0; i < N_ - 1; i++) {
                double dx = x[2 * (i + 1)] - x[2 * i];
                double dy = x[2 * (i + 1) + 1] - x[2 * i + 1];
                double dist = std::sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
                values[2 * i] = dx / dist;
                values[2 * i + 1] = dy / dist;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Define the gradient of the objective function
    virtual bool eval_grad_f(Index n, const Number* x, bool new_x, Number* grad_f) {
        // Implement the gradient evaluation
        for (int i = 0; i < N_; i++) {
            grad_f[2 * i] = 0.0; // Gradient of the x-coordinate
            grad_f[2 * i + 1] = 0.0; // Gradient of the y-coordinate
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Method to finalize the solution
    virtual void finalize_solution(
        Ipopt::SolverReturn status, // Change this type to Ipopt::SolverReturn
        Ipopt::Index n,
        const Ipopt::Number* x,
        const Ipopt::Number* z_L,
        const Ipopt::Number* z_U,
        Ipopt::Index m,
        const Ipopt::Number* g,
        const Ipopt::Number* lambda,
        Ipopt::Number obj_value,
        const Ipopt::IpoptData* ip_data,
        Ipopt::IpoptCalculatedQuantities* ip_cq
    ) {
        if (status == Ipopt::SUCCESS) { // Change this comparison to Ipopt::SUCCESS
            // Write the optimal points to a CSV file
            std::ofstream outFile("optimal_points.csv");
            for (int i = 0; i < N_; i++) {
                outFile << x[2 * i] << "," << x[2 * i + 1] << std::endl;
            }
            outFile.close();
            std::cout << "Optimal points saved to 'optimal_points.csv'." << std::endl;
        }
    }

private:
    int N_; // Number of points
    double distance_; // Constraint distance
    std::vector<double> obstacle_; // Obstacle position
    std::vector<double> pinit_; // Initial point
    std::vector<double> pfin_; // Final point
};

int main() {
    int N = 30; // Number of points
    double distance = 2; // Constraint distance
    std::vector<double> obstacle = {4.0, 4.0};
    std::vector<double> pinit = {0.0, 0.0};
    std::vector<double> pfin = {10.0, 10.0};

    SmartPtr<TNLP> pointSetProblem = new PointSetProblem(N, distance, obstacle, pinit, pfin);
    SmartPtr<IpoptApplication> app = IpoptApplicationFactory();

    // Set the Hessian approximation method to limited-memory
    app->Options()->SetStringValue("hessian_approximation", "limited-memory");

    app->RethrowNonIpoptException(true);
    ApplicationReturnStatus status = app->Initialize();
    if (status != Solve_Succeeded) {
        std::cout << "IPOPT initialization failed!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    status = app->OptimizeTNLP(pointSetProblem);

    if (status == Solve_Succeeded || status == Solved_To_Acceptable_Level) {
        Number obj_value;
        Number x[2 * N];
        pointSetProblem->eval_f(2 * N, x, true, obj_value);

        std::cout << "Optimal points:" << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            std::cout << "Point " << i + 1 << ": (" << x[2 * i] << ", " << x[2 * i + 1] << ")" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "Optimal Objective Value: " << obj_value << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "IPOPT optimization failed with status " << status << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that my code satisfies all the required tasks except for this one:

`• there is no point lying on a circle or radius 1 centered at (4, 4);`

That's why I added this part of the code for creating some obstacle:

```
// Add constraints to avoid the circle of radius 1 centered at (4, 4)
        for (int i = 0; i < N_; i++) {
            double dx = x_l[2 * i] - obstacle_[0];
            double dy = x_l[2 * i + 1] - obstacle_[1];
            double distance_squared = dx * dx + dy * dy;
            g_l[N_ - 1 + i] = -1e20; // Ensure points are outside the circle
            g_u[N_ - 1 + i] = 1e20; // A large upper bound to ensure the circle constraint is not violated
    }
```

And the thing is that when the last two lines are commented out :

```
g_l[N_ - 1 + i] = -1e20; 
g_u[N_ - 1 + i] = 1e20;
```

the code can be compiled but it doesn't affect the location of the points (because I didn't give the upper and lower bounds)
But when they are not commented out it can be compiled again but when I run the program the Ipopt library gives the following error:

```
******************************************************************************
This program contains Ipopt, a library for large-scale nonlinear optimization.
 Ipopt is released as open source code under the Eclipse Public License (EPL).
         For more information visit https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt
******************************************************************************

This is Ipopt version 3.14.13, running with linear solver MUMPS 5.6.0.

malloc(): invalid size (unsorted)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What can be the problem? Why should I do? Thank you for your time in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! I looked at your code to find out where `g_l` and `g_u` variables are defined but couldn't find it. How are they defined? The `malloc` error indicates that you are accessing an invalid memory!